updater = Updater(bot=TOKEN, use_context=True) TypeError: Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_context'
im trying to create a telegram bot but im getting this error
updater = Updater(bot=TOKEN, use_context=True)    TypeError: Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_context'

when i try to run this code
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters

TOKEN = 'mine_BOT_TOKEN'

def start_command(update, context):
    """Greets the user and offers to find a match."""
    update.message.reply_text('Hello! Let\'s find you a match')  # Use double quotes for string

def echo(update, context):
    """Echos the user message."""
    update.message.reply_text(update.message.text)

def main():
    """Starts the Telegram bot."""
    updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)  # Use token for Updater
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_command))
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, echo))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


My first impression is a version mismatch. Perhaps this code is old and incompatible with the version of Telegram that you are using. I am unfamiliar with Telegram. If I were confronted with this problem myself, I would start taking a look at the documentation of Telegram (and perhaps a list of recent breaking changes in the version history as well).

Does this answer your question? TypeError: Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_context'
